# PREVENT Speech Recognizer from Dictating

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a spelling bee training program for my son.
I can get the speech recognizer to work from C# without a problem.

The issue is: I only want it to recognize the spoken letters and NEVER try to turn them into words.

How do I stop the recognizer from translating the letters into words?

Example: I say, "P Q R" and the recognizer outputs "PQ are".

Help Mr. Wizard!

-- Paul

Comment: This is really tough task in my opinion. Have you tried anything? are you using Microsoft Speech Rec. Package?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried this (just had a quick look at it right now), I'd assume you're looking for something like this:

```
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();

Choices letters = new Choices();
letters.add(new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", ...});

gb.append(letters);

Grammer grammar(gb); // this grammar is then be used and should only support the specific subset as defined above.
```

Answer (score 0):

do u have the source code of the c# recognizer, if yes you need to edit it to disable the part of the code which is responsible for translating the spoken letters into words